# GPG4Win Decrypt Multiple files to a Different Directory

Tags: automation, pgp

I have a requirement to download PGP files from a 3rd Party SFTP server and then decrypt them and move to a the company file server.  I am going to use WinSCP to download the files to an Inbound folder and then use WGPG4Win to decrypt the files in that folder.

For testing I am using the following command decrypt the files I will look into calling the passphrase from another file later:

gpg --passphrase Password --decrypt-files C:\PGP_Test\Inbound*

I guess my question has 2 options:

Option1

Is it possible to send the decrypted files to another folder.  I have tried --output but it seems that is limited to single files rather than all files in a folder.

Option2:

Is there a switch to delete the source file following decryption?

It isn't a deal breaker if I can't do either as I can just run another command to move any file with *.gpg to an archive folder to keep it all neat and tidy.